# How can I get 2nd and last column content in tsv files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cut

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r line; do
echo "$line" | cut -d '   ' -f1-3
done
```

What do I put in place of -3 or is there any way around?

Comment: `awk -F$'\t' '{print $2, $NF}' file.tsv`

Answer (score 0):

I would splitting the whole line into different variables will get you where you want to go. Given this input file:

```
$ cat inputFile.txt 
ya1 ya2 ya3 ya4
ye1 ye2 ye3 ye4
yi1 yi2 yi3 yi4
yo1 yo2 yo3 yo4
yu1 yu2 yu3 yu4
```

You could process your columns like below. You can capture them but you don't have to do anything with them; notice cols 1 and 3 are junk1 and junk3 in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# initialize the file                                                              
cat /dev/null > file.tsv                                                           
                                                                                   
# process second and last column                                                   
while IFS=$'\t' read -r junk1 var2 junk3 var4; do                                  
    echo "$var2,$var4" >> file.tsv                                                 
done < inputFile.txt                                                               
                                                                                   
# Display TSV file                                                                 
cat file.tsv
```

Then, check your output file:

```
$ cat file.tsv 
ya2,ya4
ye2,ye4
yi2,yi4
yo2,yo4
yu2,yu4
```

Only the 2nd and last column content are in tsv file.

REF: [Field splitting, whitespace trimming, and other input processing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing)

Comment: i found another way, i just used to 'cut' command in bash: cut -f 2-